# "cd" into directory containg space in name

Tags: command-line

So I have been using Ubuntu for a few months now, and have come across a very noob terminal question.

I want to go from home -> Documents -> My Programs

I am able to get into my documents folder by doing

```
cd ./Documents
```

But when I want to go into "My Programs", I am unable to do so because of the space between "My" and "Programs". Is there a different syntax I must use to access this folder via terminal?

Comment: Put a "\" after "My" when typing it in.  So it would look like `cd My\ Programs/`

Comment: You need to escape the space in between characters with \, in your case `My\ Programs`. Alternatively, you can get bash to autocomplete the address by simply typing `My` then pressing the Tab key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can quote the whole directory name or escape the space in between the words.

In a nutshell, do any one of the following:

```
cd 'My Programs'
cd "My Programs"
cd My\ Programs
```